# Trigger Github actions workflow on previously built commits

Tags: git, github, github-actions

My team has limited staging environments to test on, so we built a custom tool to deploy multiple branches on the same system for testing and development. For two feature branches that are being developed on (`featureA` and `featureB`), the tool essentially wraps the following git commands:

If the "deployed set" is `[featureA]` then that will go out as:

```
git checkout main
git merge featureA
git push -f origin/deploy-tool/{{env}}
```

The Github action watches for pushes to `/origin/deploy-tool/{{env}}`.

If you then deploy "featureB", it makes the deployed_set [featureA, featureB] and does this:

```
git checkout main
git merge featureA
git merge featureB
git push -f origin/tardis/{{env}}
```

The problem comes when you have situation where you want to undeploy one of these branches, say, due to a bug that is blocking testing, etc...
If you "undeploy" `featureB`, it then the deployed_set becomes `[featureA]` again, so it runs:

```
git checkout main
git merge featureA
git push -f origin/tardis/{{env}}
```

Unfortunately, this will have the exact same commit and sha as the first example, and Github actions will not trigger on the push.

Looking for suggestions either on the github push event trigger or git commands that will basically allow us to "revert" a branch merge, but make it look like something new that will trigger the action.